# Extracting a file in Python3 to a directory

Tags: python, directory, extract, zip

Let's just say the variable "x" is where the file to be extracted is located and "Y" is where I want to extract it to. I have these set in another .py file. So how would I do this? I tried using the code below but cmd kept giving me a "zipthis.zip not found". I have the .zip on my desktop inside a file called source. Summary of my ramblings: I want to extract a .zip to another location. Thanks in advance.

```
import zipfile
fh = open('zipthis.zip', 'rb')
z = zipfile.ZipFile(fh)
for name in z.namelist():
outpath = "C:\\"
z.extract(name, outpath)
```

Comment: You should try specifying an absolute location to `zipthis.zip`. I'm not familar with Windows, but it's probably something like `C:/Users/username/Desktop/zipthis.zip` - as a side note, your indentation is wrong but I assume that was as a result of pasting it into the question box.

Comment: Thanks, now there is no error message in the cmd and when I run the file it flashes a blank cmd. Also though it's not extracting/unzipping the file. Sorry about indents this is my first question.

Comment: You should print the result of `namelist` to make sure it is what you expect, `print(z.namelist())`.

Comment: Alright when I run with `namelist` it returns ['zipthis/Test.txt'] But the file still doesn't seem to have been extracted.

Comment: Hmm, it looks like it should work then. It could be worth looking through the [docs](http://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile#zipfile.ZipFile.extract) and perhaps switching to `infolist` instead of `namelist`.

Comment: Oh hah. I got it. I for some reason expected it to extract to the same file. I just realized I had it set to C:\\. It works now, sorry.